# cocos2d-iphone action is interrupted by ongoing operations

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, action, nsthread

I want to run an action and go on go on processing game logic at the same time, but action is interrupted when the process is going on. I tried to use thread, but I couldn't make it work. When it's not needed to process game logic the sprites move as I expected, but when it's needed to make some operations during action, the action is interrupted during the operation time. After the operation is ended, the action is going on.
What am I doing wrong?

I call a selector as follows - the selector starts the action.

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(moveSprite:)
                         toTarget:self
                       withObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                   sprite, @"sprite",
                                                   [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pos], @"pos",
                                                   nil]];


-(void) moveSprite: (NSDictionary*) parameters {
    CCSprite *sprite = [parameters objectForKey:@"sprite"];
    CGPoint pos = [[parameters objectForKey:@"pos"] CGPointValue];
    id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.4f position:pos];
    id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(removeSprite:data:) data:(__bridge void*)sprite];
    [sprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];
}
```

After the action ends I remove the sprite by following method.

```
-(void) removeSprite: (id)sender data:(void*)data {
    CCSprite *sprite = (__bridge CCSprite*)data;
    [self removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES];
}
```

Comment: Also you need to show the part of your game logic that causes the block. It must be very intense to stop the game from rendering.

Comment: I didn't know the reason to accept. thanks for your warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it makes no sense to create actions in a separate thread. The actions are added to the node, and the node along with its actions are updated on the main thread.

You should also know that threading will *only* help you if the device has two or more CPU cores. On a single core device (iPhone 4 or earlier, iPod Touch 4 or earlier, iPad 1) running a separate thread that performs heavy duty operations will still slow down if not halt the main thread.

If your game logic is that heavy that it actually *halts* the screen updates, you need to optimize whatever you're doing. You could spread the calculation across multiple frames, profile to see if you can optimize, or if you're using a brute force approach research more clever, less straightforward but faster algorithms.

Comment: I'm iterating on mutable array and making comparison using attributes of object, also I'm creating new mutable arrays. I guess array operations halt the main thread. I'll try to optimize operations.

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2d is running on the main thread, your heavy operation runs there too, so what you're experiencing is quite normal.

You should either make tha operation lighter, or use threads, so your CCActions code is not what you should be looking for, since you know it works ok without the costly operation

Comment: Actually I thought that when I create a thread for the method that initializes the action, the action would work parallel to main thread and the action would not be interrupted by main thread. Should I also use thread for other operations?

Comment: It would be better to avoid threads and make your costly function lighter first.